# react native webview:when add baseRrl,then just show html string

Tags: webview, react-native

In order to achieve the WebView display custom font
on rn 0.28:

```
    var html = 'test';
    html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: "MyFont";
                src: url("fonts/fzbys.ttf");
            }
            body{font-family: "MyFont"; font-size:28px;}
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>`+html+`
            </body>
            </html>`;
    return (
        <View style={[{width:this.state.width, alignItems:'center'}, this.props.styles]}>
            <WebView 
                ref={"wv"}
                style={{width:this.state.width, height:100}}
                source={{html:html, baseUrl:"file:///android_asset/"}} 
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true} />
        </View>
        );
```

the font file had in android/app/src/main/assets/fonts, then :
[run res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fCtD.png)

Comment: Have you tried just to inject a custom JS code with your font? So for example to set your body font family and size?

Comment: @NinetyHH I don't understand what you mean~I just set 'baseUrl' and simple HTML content, still get the same results.

Comment: Success:[link](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android)
Don't know why....